# Contraction of a lightlike vector with another vector (free cordinate)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, inner-products, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove that there exist always a vector w whose contraction with a lightlike vector u ($g(u,u)= 0$) it's always different from zero:

$$g(u,v)\ne 0$$

I know how to do this with coordinates, but in a free cordinate scheme I'm totally lost.

Any help?

PD: Both vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: This is not true. Consider $u^\mu=(1,1,0,0)$ and $v^\mu=(0,0,1,0)$; $u^\mu$ is lightlike, but $u^\mu v_\mu=0$.

Comment: Thats weird. My exercise follows as: Prove that if one of the vectors $v_i ∈ S$ is lightlike, then there exists a second vector $v_j ∈ S$,
$i\ne j$, such that $g(v_i, v_j )\ne 0$. Maybe the other vector has to be timelike, so it mantains the result? S is a linearly independent set.

Comment: There's a difference between saying there exists a vector that is not orthogonal (which is true) and saying all other vectors are not orthogonal (which is not true generally, but is true for timelike and lightlike vectors).

Comment: You are totally right, gonna edit the question.